# SharePoint : how to get the list static name via web service method

Tags: sharepoint, wss

When I create a list in sharepoint using a feature I specify the staticName which becomes part of the URL to the list.

When I query the list, and want to get the name - now all the sharepoint web service sends back is the ID, for example: Name=\"{1836D8BB-77D3-4266-AA09-1ABB68E5C672}\"

How can I get the static name again?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GetList` method in the Lists.asmx web-service will return a field called DefaultViewUrl. It'll look like this :

```
DefaultViewUrl="/Site_Name/Lists/List_Name/AllItems.aspx"
```

The following code would then give you the static name :

```
String pattern = ".*/(?<listStaticName>.+)/[^\\.]+\\.aspx";
Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(DefaultViewUrl);
String listStaticName = matches[0].Groups["listStaticName"].ToString();
```

Far from an elegant solution, but it will work.

EDIT : Actually, the SPList.RootFolder.Name should give you the same result for a document library.